# The conga page is getting there,But Facing error Parameter Id missing?

Tags: apex, visualforce, button, conga

when i select the records in vf page ,after click on the VF Button the conga should be call along with id for generating the PDF but on button click the window is opening but showing error that "ID Parameter is missing" ?

VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}"  onclick="openConga()" reRender="table1"/>

<Script Language="JavaScript"> 
             function openConga() 
                { 
                    window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Payment__c.Generate_PDF, Payment_Id)}', '','scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes, toolbar=no,location=yes,status=yes');

        </Script>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference GenerateInvoice() 
            {
            selectedEsr = new List<Payment__c>();
            for(wrappayment wp : paymentList)
                {
                    if(wp.selected == true) 
                    {  Payment_Id=wp.pay.id; 
 }
        }

        return null;
            }
```

Comment: [‎28-‎01-‎2019 12:44]  Sakhare, Ankita:  
using command ::<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}"  onclick="openConga()" reRender="table1"/>

Answer (score 0):

In which page does the error appear? Based on the codes you have given, the error should be somewhere between here `{!URLFOR($Action.Payment__c.Generate_PDF, Payment_Id)}`, did you try to debug the `Payment_Id` parameter and see if it is empty?

Comment: ..error is on the cong page